# Android JSON parsing using Volley

Tags: android, json, gson, android-volley

Ok so an answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29987024/android-application-crashing-on-3g-slow-connection-but-works-over-wifi) suggested for Volley implementation. I did try some examples, read some articles and yeah I'm kinda excited about Volley, it can make my apps life easier. but there is not a lot of documentation out there and for I newbie like me, I found it very hard implementing it.

Here is where I'm stuck:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    StringRequest movieReq = new StringRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    try {
                            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
                            for (int z = 0; z < jsonArray.length(); z++) {
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(z);
                                String url = jsonObject1.getString("url");
                                String title = jsonObject1.getString("title");
                                String content = jsonObject1.getString("content");
                                map.put(SHAREURL, url);
                                map.put(TITLE, title);
                                map.put(CONTENT, content);
                                JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("attachments");
                                for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                    String urlImage = jsonObject2.getString("url");
                                    map.put(URL, urlImage);
                                    arrayList.add(map);

                                }
                            }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    listView = (ListView) mActivity.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(mActivity, arrayList);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }



  },new Response.ErrorListener(){
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
  }
});
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
```

This is the page formatted using JSON

```
"posts" : [{
"title":"Fast and Furious",
"url":"example.com",
"content":"example",
"attachments":[{
"url":"example.jpg" }]}]
```

Comment: Volley also has JsonObjectRequest  but if you take String as response then why not use Gson or Jackson library which deserializes your text in about one line ?

Comment: I have never used Gson or Jackson, just point me in the right direction, not to much experience over here

Comment: If you want I can code in Gson how it works.

Comment: that will be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it with Gson. 
The first order of business is to add the library. I sure hope you are using Android Studio so you can add this in your build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

And then we imitate the response as corresponding plain old java object (POJO). Basically we define several classes whose members reflect the type and the name of those in the json text, like this. (you need to match this with the response text of your example)

```
class Attachment {
   private String url;  

   public String getUrl(){
      return url;
   }       

   public String setUrl(String url){
      this.url = url;
   }
}

class Post {
   private String title; //make sure each variable name is the same 
                         //as the field in json text
   private String url;
   private String content;
   private ArrayList<Attachment> attachments;

   // add getters and setters as needed. Again this can be accomplished easily
   // in Android Studio
}

class Wrap {
  private ArrayList<Post> posts;
}
```

Now we go back to your Volley.onResponse where we simply do this

```
  @Override
  public void onResponse(String response) {
     Wrap wrap = new Gson().fromJson(response, Wrap.class);        
  }
```

There you go, just one line, skipping all the painful iteration.
Now that you have this Wrap object you can get or set any of its content easily. Say to get the title of first post just do

```
String titleOfFirstPost = wrap.getPosts().get(0).getTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @inmyth for constructing a simple solution to my problem. I ended up with this code in the onResponse method:

```
 public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Wrap wrap = new Gson().fromJson(response, Wrap.class);

                    for(Post post : wrap.getPosts()){
                        adapter.add(post);
                    }
```

You can see the entire code over [here](https://github.com/Pirat4e/KinoApplication)